# Problem finding .bib files

Tags: bibtex

My citations are all rendered as `[&]` and my bibliography is not printed.

My source includes the line `\bibliography{NonIdealGrads}` The file `NonIdealGrads.bib` is in the project and is included in the file window.

All the references are in `NonIdealGrads.bib.`
Why isn't the .bib file read properly?

Related error:

> BibTeX I couldn't open style file vancouver-authoryear.bst :
>   \bibstyle{vancouver-authoryear : }

The file `vancouver-authoryear.bst` is in the project and in the file window.

Comment: Why is there a colon after the bibstyle?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Could you please add all parts of your preamble that are relevant for the bibliography to your question? And indeed that colon looks suspicious, but I tried it with some bibliographies and it actually gives me the same correct output as regular `\bibstyle{vancouver-authoryear}`, using biblatex.